# Using an external React component on Rails application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs

I am trying to use the [rc-slider](https://github.com/react-component/slider) `React` component on a existing `Rails` application that is using [react-rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) `gem` and it already have some other components that were built within the application that work just fine.

Based on [this blog post](http://rmosolgo.github.io/blog/2016/05/19/how-i-use-sprockets/) I've been able to follow its first 3 steps, I've found the minified and browser-ready version of it [here](https://unpkg.com/rc-slider@6.0.0/dist/rc-slider.min.js), added the file to the suggested path and required it on the `application.js` as recommended but even seeing the code within the `Sprockets` generated application javascript file that is rendered on the browser I can't see or use the supposed global variable it would provide according to step 4.

In the component's [examples page](http://react-component.github.io/slider/examples/handle.html) it uses a `const Slider = require('rc-slider');` statement in order to get that available. I've tried that but without luck as it throws: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. The same happens when I try the [`README`](https://github.com/react-component/slider#usage) usage's section approach: `import Slider, { Range } from 'rc-slider';`. I've tried both from an existing JS where I load other React components and also from the browser's Dev Tools Console window.

Am I using the wrong approach to the problem or maybe missing/overseeing any concept or basics here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Sprockets, you can get a pre-compiled version of rc-slider from unpkg:

https://unpkg.com/rc-slider@6.0.0/dist/rc-slider.js

Taking a look at the source, I see it exports the library as `rc-slider`:

[image: rc-slider exported to window]

So you can access it as `window["rc-slider"]` and use it from there, for example:

```
var RCSlider = window["rc-slider"]

var container = document.getElementById("container")

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <RCSlider />
    <RCSlider.Range />
  </div>,
  container
);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/75081e0g/)

That way, if you put `rc-slider.js` in the asset pipeline, you can use `RCSlider` in your javascripts.